# TinyMCE Inlite Theme doesnt work with <textarea>

Tags: tinymce, django-tinymce

I have this setup:

```
tinymce.init ({
selector: '#tinymce',
theme: 'inlite',
plugins: 'image table link paste contextmenu textpattern autolink charmap media hr spellchecker',
insert_toolbar: 'quickimage quicktable charmap media',
selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h1 h2 h3 hr blockquote',
inline: true,
```

});

The TinyMCE inlite theme works fine when I use it with div tag but when i switch it over to textarea tag the theme doesnt work.

This works:

```
<div id="tinymce">
```

This does not work:

```
<textarea id="tinymce">
```

I have tried several configurations but cannot seem to get it working. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `inlite` theme is only intended for use in the **inline** mode of TinyMCE:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/themes/inlite/

> The inlite theme is responsible for rendering the editor lightweight
>   inline mode.